# How to update ApplicationVersion item in a C# Project File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, csproj

I know that from project properties\Application and then clicking on "Assembly Information..." button, you can change the version for Assembly and File in the "Assembly version" and "File version" fields respectively. They can also be changed from Assemblyinfo.cs file under Properties folder (It's the same).

Maybe it's an stupid question...But how can I change the version for "ApplicationVersion" item within the csproj file? Can it be changed somewhere from the project properties UI? or the only way is to change it manually from the csproj file?

Also, what is the difference between all them (Assembly version, File version and ApplicationVersion)?

Comment: Recommend you also google Directory.Build.props

Comment: @BentTranberg yeap, i have found things about Directory.Build.props and how to update it automatically. But just now I am not interested on an automatically update. In fact, I would like to know why ApplicattionVersion is not automatically updated when I update assembly version and file version. Also I would like to know what is exactly the difference between ApplicationVersion, Assembly version and File version.

Comment: There are several hundred answers about these matters here on SO, of which a great many go into great detail. There is also plenty of documentation spread throughout the net.